# how many layers of symlink can linux resolve

Tags: linux, symlink

I am reading The Linux Programming Interface, this book says:

> SUSv3 requires that an implementation allow at least `_POSIX_SYMLOOP_MAX` dereferences of each symbolic link component of a pathname. The specified value for `_POSIX_SYMLOOP_MAX` is `8`. However, before kernel 2.6.18, Linux imposed a limit of 5 dereferences when following a chain of symbolic links. **Starting with kernel 2.6.18, Linux implements the SUSv3-specified minimum of 8 dereferences. Linux also imposes a total of 40 dereferences for an entire pathname.**

I didn't quite understand the **last two sentences**, what is the difference between these `8` and `40` limitations? I tested myself, creating a bunch of symlinks in my machine to try to reach the limitation:

```bash
$ l
Permissions Links Size User  Group Date Modified Name
.rw-r--r--@     1   12 steve steve 20 Oct 16:35  a
lrwxrwxrwx@     1    1 steve steve 20 Oct 16:34  b -> a
lrwxrwxrwx@     1    1 steve steve 20 Oct 16:35  c -> b
lrwxrwxrwx@     1    1 steve steve 20 Oct 16:35  d -> c
lrwxrwxrwx@     1    1 steve steve 20 Oct 16:35  e -> d
lrwxrwxrwx@     1    1 steve steve 20 Oct 16:36  f -> e
lrwxrwxrwx@     1    1 steve steve 20 Oct 16:36  g -> f
lrwxrwxrwx@     1    1 steve steve 20 Oct 16:36  h -> g
lrwxrwxrwx@     1    1 steve steve 20 Oct 16:36  i -> h
lrwxrwxrwx@     1    1 steve steve 20 Oct 16:36  j -> i
lrwxrwxrwx@     1    1 steve steve 20 Oct 16:37  k -> i
lrwxrwxrwx@     1    1 steve steve 20 Oct 16:37  l -> k
lrwxrwxrwx@     1    1 steve steve 20 Oct 16:37  m -> l
lrwxrwxrwx@     1    1 steve steve 20 Oct 16:37  n -> m
lrwxrwxrwx@     1    1 steve steve 20 Oct 16:38  o -> n
lrwxrwxrwx@     1    1 steve steve 20 Oct 16:38  p -> o
lrwxrwxrwx@     1    1 steve steve 20 Oct 16:40  q -> p
lrwxrwxrwx@     1    1 steve steve 20 Oct 16:41  r -> q
lrwxrwxrwx@     1    1 steve steve 20 Oct 16:41  s -> r
lrwxrwxrwx@     1    1 steve steve 20 Oct 16:41  t -> s
lrwxrwxrwx@     1    1 steve steve 20 Oct 16:41  u -> t
lrwxrwxrwx@     1    1 steve steve 20 Oct 16:41  v -> u
lrwxrwxrwx@     1    1 steve steve 20 Oct 16:41  w -> v
lrwxrwxrwx@     1    1 steve steve 20 Oct 16:41  x -> w
lrwxrwxrwx@     1    1 steve steve 20 Oct 16:41  y -> x
lrwxrwxrwx@     1    1 steve steve 20 Oct 16:41  z -> y
lrwxrwxrwx@     1    1 steve steve 20 Oct 16:42  z1 -> z
lrwxrwxrwx@     1    2 steve steve 20 Oct 16:42  z2 -> z1
lrwxrwxrwx@     1    2 steve steve 20 Oct 16:42  z3 -> z2
lrwxrwxrwx@     1    2 steve steve 20 Oct 16:42  z4 -> z3
lrwxrwxrwx@     1    2 steve steve 20 Oct 16:43  z5 -> z4
lrwxrwxrwx@     1    2 steve steve 20 Oct 16:43  z6 -> z5
lrwxrwxrwx@     1    2 steve steve 20 Oct 16:43  z7 -> z6
lrwxrwxrwx@     1    2 steve steve 20 Oct 16:43  z8 -> z7
lrwxrwxrwx@     1    2 steve steve 20 Oct 16:43  z9 -> z8
lrwxrwxrwx@     1    2 steve steve 20 Oct 16:43  z10 -> z9
lrwxrwxrwx@     1    3 steve steve 20 Oct 16:43  z11 -> z10
lrwxrwxrwx@     1    3 steve steve 20 Oct 16:43  z12 -> z11
lrwxrwxrwx@     1    3 steve steve 20 Oct 16:43  z13 -> z12
lrwxrwxrwx@     1    3 steve steve 20 Oct 16:44  z14 -> z13
lrwxrwxrwx@     1    3 steve steve 20 Oct 16:44  z15 -> z14
lrwxrwxrwx@     1    3 steve steve 20 Oct 16:44  z16 -> z15
lrwxrwxrwx      1    3 steve steve 20 Oct 16:45  z17 -> z16
```

```bash
$ cat a
You did it.

$ cat z17
cat: z17: Too many levels of symbolic links

$  cat z16
You did it.
```

Seems that I have triggered that `40` limitation, then what is that `8` one?

Comment: 8 sounds like a lower limit that any POSIX system must support, and 40 seems to be the upper limit that Linux imposes.

Comment: If I read it correctly it says 8 must be supported no matter what, anything about it is optional. Probably it was a config option in the past but it's long been removed, so now we have 40.

Comment: @Kusalananda @Artem S. Tashkinov Thanks for your comments. So these two limitations are limiting the same thing, `8` is the POSIX minimal limit that any implementations must follow, and `40` is the limit defined by Linux.

Comment: On a side note, you can also learn from man path_resolution that *"In Linux 4.2, the kernel's pathname-resolution code was reworked to eliminate the use of recursion"*.

Comment: @MC68020 Thanks!  In Linux 4.2, the kernel's pathname-resolution code was reworked to eliminate the use of recursion, so that **the only limit that remains** is the maximum of 40 resolutions for the entire pathname. This makes it more clear, `40` is technically NOT the upper limit of symlink resolving, it is the maximum `path resolution`  we can use for a single path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two limitations are limiting **the same thing**.

`8`, as defined in `_POSIX_SYMLOOP_MAX`, is the POSIX **minimal** limit that every POSIX-conforming OS must follow.

When it comes to a specific OS, the OS can choose a different limit value as long as it satisfies the POSIX minimal limit (i.e., bigger than or equal to `8`).

Linux after kernel 2.6.18, chose `8`. In kernel 4.2, the kernel's pathname-resolution code was reworked to eliminate the use of recursion, so right now, the **only bottleneck** that limits symlink resolution is how many times of `path resolution` we can use for a single path, this value is 40. So the maximum number of symbolic links that will be followed while resolving a pathname is 40